# StoryBoard - UITabBarController + UINavigationController - Jumping from one navigation controller to the other one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I have the following storyboard setup

I need to jump from the BodyMapViewController to MoleDetailsView controller (as shown in the image) when the user hit the save button

I can use the modal view which is very easy but the issue is that I want the user to be able to go back to the MoleHistory and dermalHistory views from the MoleDetailsView

basically I need to do the following steps:

- switch the tab
- Navigate trough the DermalHistoryView and then MoleHistoryView to get to the MoleDetails view

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you need to switch tabs and manually modify the view hierarchy so the correct view is showing.

First, grab the navigation controller controlling the other tab. With that, you can then instantiate a view hierarchy with an NSMutableArray like follows:

```
-(void)pushToMoleDetailViewController:(id)detailItem
{

    UINavigationController *navCon = [self.navigationController.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex: 1];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
    DermalHistoryViewController *dermalHistory = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DermalHistoryViewController"]

    //configure dermal history here


    NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController].viewControllers mutableCopy];
    [viewControllers addObject: dermalHistory];

    MoleHistoryViewController *moleHistory = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MoleHistoryViewController"]

    //configure mole history here
    [viewControllers addObject: moleHistory];

    MoleDetailsViewController *moleDetails = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MoleDetailsViewController"]

    //configure mole details here
    [viewControllers addObject: moleDetails];



    navCon.viewControllers = viewControllers;
    self.navigationController.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

Take a look at this question:
[Push segue without animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383038/push-segue-without-animation)

Comment: keep in mind that this does not quite meet the user interface guidelines. All all operations that show additional details should be able to pop back to the same view. I would think a little bit more about the style that you want the app to appear in because this design could be a little bit confusing for users.

Comment: WOW thanks a lot for your answer it worked!! the only thing that I changed was to set the viewControllers array to an empty array instead of the current view controllers so I dont see the camera and bodyMap views when I hit the back button.